# Retrieving data from all possible slack groups using slack api

Tags: slack-api

Is there a way to get data from all possible slack groups? I am working on a project where I want to mine data from a specific type of slack groups. Suppose I want to do get data from all Python related groups - some of which I might not be a part of.

Is there a way to do this with Slack API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot see or access private channels that you are not a member of.

You can get a list of channels that you do have access to via the [`conversations.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list) API, and you can read the messages using the [`conversations.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) API.